# VBA add value of var in a var declaration

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to select a sheet based upon a value in a different sheet

```
MySheet = Sheets("Template").Range("L41").Value
Set wks = Sheets("MySheet")
```

I understand that the "" marks represent string so the code won't get executed.

Being used to `php` I can "connect" strings with a single `.`

This is not the case here. What I thought of doing was this:

```
MySheet = ".Sheets("Template").Range("L41").Value."
Set wks = Sheets(MySheet)
```

Comment: Change first code, second line to `Set wks = Sheets(MySheet)` and it should work!

Comment: This for the second attempt `Set wks = Sheets(Sheets("Template").Range("L41").Value)`

Comment: In all cases VBA states an error: subscript out of range

Comment: Out of range means that the cell value is not a String of a name of a sheet or a valid number of Sheets collection.

Comment: If I hover Set wks it shows: wks=nothing and if I hover Sheets(MySheet) it shows: MySheet = "<the sheet name>"

Comment: The sheet name and the value in cell L4 must be **exactly** the same for your code to work

Comment: It is. If I run a msgBox it shows the value I want to see

Comment: FUCK. I was checking the wrong sheet... Thanks guys it works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would work for you.

```
Sub test()

    Dim strMySheet As String
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    
    strMySheet = Sheets("Template").Range("L41").Value
    Set wks = Sheets(strMySheet)

End Sub
```

Comment: You don't *have to* rename `MySheet` to `strMySheet` - but I did so as to remove any confusion about its Type.